# Relabel variables in a loop--invalid syntax?

Tags: loops, label, stata

I have a list of variables that I need to relabel. I created paired locals and a loop to rename them like so:

```
local demo var1                             ///
var2                                        ///     
var3                                        ///
var4                                        ///
var5                                        /// 
var6

local varlabel "label 1"                    ///
"label 2"                                   ///
"label 3"                                   ///
"label 4"                                   /// 
"label 5"                                   ///
"label 6"                                       

    * Count number of variables in local
    local mydemocount: word count `demo'
    
    
    * Loop through all variables
    forval mycounter = 1/`mydemocount' {
        local myvar:     word `mycounter' of `demo'
        local myvarlabel:        word `mycounter' of `varlabel'
        
        label var `myvar' "`myvarlabel'"
        
    }
```

However, I am getting an "invalid syntax" error. Can someone help me identify the problem here? Is there maybe a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To test this code, a sandbox dataset is needed with the variables in question. Otherwise the main bug is the need to use compound double quotes. Without compound double quotes, the outermost double quotes get stripped on defining `varlabel`, which is not what you want.

```
* sandbox 
clear
set obs 1 
forval j = 1/6 { 
    gen var`j' = 42 
} 

* fixed code 
local demo var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
local varlabel `" "label 1"  "label 2" "label 3" "label 4" "label 5" "label 6" "'    

* Count number of variables in local
local mydemocount: word count `demo'
    
* Loop through all variables
forval mycounter = 1/`mydemocount' {
    local myvar: word `mycounter' of `demo'
    local myvarlabel: word `mycounter' of `varlabel'   
    label var `myvar' "`myvarlabel'"
}
```

The example may naturally be proxy for a much more elaborate example, but even so it's a lot simpler to have one statement defining each variable label. The code puts all the variable names into one local and all the variable labels into another local -- and then the code has to take them out again. That is like putting several left gloves into one box, several right gloves into another box and taking them out of the boxes to pair them off. The boxing and unboxing are not needed.

Loops are great, but not when it is easier just to spell out the individual statements.

Concretely put, this is a roundabout way to execute 6 statements of which

```
label var var1 "label 1"
```

is representative.

On the other hand, if we take the problem literally, that could be a loop:

```
forval j = 1/6 { 
    label var var`j' "label `j'" 
}
```

but my guess is that you don't really want that, just as having names like `var1` is a poor choice when evocative names are possible. Abstracting the problem sometimes obscures the real problem.