# Invalid syntax in Stata putexcel loop?

Tags: loops, stata, export-to-excel

I am writing a program to export data by year using putexcel code, and am unsure where the error is in the following:

```
* Create paired locals for years
    local year 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
    local col B D F H J L
    local name year1 year2 year3 year4 year5 year6
    
    * Count number of variables in local    
        local count: word count `year'
    
    * Loop through paired locals
        forval mycounter = 1/`count'{
            local myyear:   word `mycounter' of `year'
            local mycol:    word `mycounter' of `col'
            local myname:   word `mycounter' of `name'
        

        estpost tabstat variable1 if level == 1 & year == `myyear', stat(sum) 
        mat variable1_`myname' = e(sum)
        estpost tabstat variable2 if level == 4 & year == `myyear', stat(count)
        mat variable2_`myname' = e(count)
        
        mat vars_`myname' = variable1_`myname', variable2_`myname' 
        putexcel `mycol'7 = matrix(vars_`myname')

    
}
```

I am getting an 'invalid syntax' error. The odd part is that the program is able to loop through and create matrices for year1 through year4. Can anyone help me identify what the problem might be? Might it be a problem with the way the loop is written or with the dataset itself? Thanks so much.

Comment: can you share a subset of your data? (Use the command `dataex` to share some data) Since you are able to run the first 4 iterations of the loop it could very well be that it is something in your data and not in your code that is creating this error.  If you cant share the data for any reason, try drop year 5 to see if you have the same problem. Or drop year 1 to see if it still crashes after year 4 or if it crashes after the 4th iteration no matter the order in your data etc.

Comment: The same point about example data was made in your previous thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946708/relabel-variables-in-a-loop-invalid-syntax  Please reply to the answer there by accepting it or by explaining how it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: After all, if your best guess is that the problem is in your data, and it's my guess too, then it follows that the information we need is about your data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but it wouldn't display well as a comment.

I agree with @TheIceBear that a reproducible example would help mightily.

You could help myself mightily by displaying results at each stage to see that you have what you think you should have.

Your code could be trimmed down considerably.

- There is little or no point in firing up `tabstat` and then pushing results through `estpost` when all you want each time is a single scalar result that `summarize` would give you directly.
- There is little or no point to creating lots of little matrices each holding a single scalar.

Although I can't test this against your data, I think it is close to your intent. Note the spirit of displaying the results matrix each time round the loop.

```
local col B D F H J L
   
forval y = 2000/2005 {
    gettoken mycol col : col 
        
    su variable1 if level == 1 & year == `y'
    scalar sum1 = r(sum)
    su variable2 if level == 4 & year == `y'
       
    mat work = sum1, r(N) 
    mat list work 
    putexcel `mycol'7 = matrix(work)
}
```

A column on parallel loops is forthcoming in *Stata Journal* 21(4) to appear around end December 2021. `gettoken` is discussed in that column.

EDIT 16 January 2022 now please see https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211063415